# vue.js - setup reactivity at runtime

Tags: vue.js

If have a situation where I want to setup my 'reactivity' programatically, at run time.

I want a function like:  dependsOn(dataValName, someOtherDataVal)  where if someOtherDataVal changes, then dataValName is updated.
  e.g.  dependsOn('a', 'b')
        if the value of b changes, then a is re-displayed/updated.

Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is vague, but what you probably need is a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). Vue will automatically detect the dependencies of computed properties. For example, there is no need to be explicit here:

```
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fullName() {
      return `${ firstName } ${ lastName }`;
    }
  }
})
```

Any time `firstName` or `lastName` changes, the computed property `fullName` will also be re-evaluated.

Comment: Computed property will not work for me as I do not know ahead of time what fields to use.    i.e. data is loaded from a database that determines what is dependent on what, hence the need for a "dependsOn" type of method.


I have noticed there is an updated() method which is called every time a field changes - I may have to roll my own logic to do this and place it there.

Comment: Yep, sounds like something you'll have to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about [*watchers*](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers). For example

```js
data: () => ({
  dataValName: 'a',
  someOtherDataVal: 'b'
}),
watch: {
  someOtherDataVal (newValue) {
    this.dataValName = 'c' // or whatever
  }
}
```

Keep in mind, computed properties are almost always a better option.

Comment: Thanks Phil, but watcher no good for me for reason listed above.

Comment: _"Listed above"_ where? Your question mentions nothing of this

Comment: See my reply to vince above.

Comment: Please add your requirements to the question